# Identify a portion of a contour that is the widest

Tags: python, opencv

Im writing a maze solving robot using opencv. My example is attached. Also a skelotonized version of the maze is attached.  Im new to opencv and my current problem is that Im not sure how identify the goal which is the square in the top left corner. I have an intermediate find contours and get the largest contour (which is the maze) can I split up the contour to find the widest area? Is there anoth way of identifying the goal.

[image: Original Maze]

Here is the result of my processing so far.

[image: Skelontized image.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use mathematical morphology here. If you will apply erosion then it will eat walls, but more thick parts (Start and Finish) will not disappear. After that you can apply dilation to restore regions size (not mandatory step).

Erosion + Dilation = Closing

After that find contours and their centers of mass, this will give you the point coordinates.